# Is it possible for Radeon cards to read data from DisplayPort (using OpenCL)?

Tags: c++, c, io, opencl, ati

Radeon is about to release videocards with DisplayPort.  What I need to do is instead of using host memory (RAM) I want to read data passing from Pegasus R6 (direct-attach RAID device) straight to video card. Perhaps using OpenCL and utilizing C/C++ on host to control the flow.

http://www.promise.com/storage/raid_series.aspx?m=192&region=en-global&rsn1=40&rsn3=47
http://techreport.com/discussions.x/13180

Greatly appreciate for your help and comments in advance.

Sincerely,

Roman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been ATi-based cards with DisplayPort such as the [PowerColor AX5770](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814131358) (which I use) for a while now.  But you are talking about connecting a storage device to a video card, and this is not feasible as far as I can tell.  The storage device you mentioned has a Thunderbolt interface, but while Thunderbolt does support DisplayPort, the converse is not true.  Thunderbolt is a hybrid interface supporting DisplayPort and PCI Express, and I would certainly assume that storage devices communicate using the PCIe mode.  So there's no way for a typical video card (which only supports DP) to host a storage device (which only supports PCIe), because while the physical and connection may be compatible, the protocols are not.